# SSE server sending events in a batch on final close

Tags: jersey

I have a Jersey server running locally, it exposes a SSE resource just like the examples here: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/sse.html. I have a local webpack Angular app, that binds to the exposed GET endpoint and listens for data. 
On the GET, I start up a thread to send notifications at regular intervals over 6-8 seconds. I don't see anything on the client UNTIL the EventOutput object is closed.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

The server code WORKS with just a simple curl, i.e.:
`curl http://localhost:8002/api/v1/notify`

But on both Chrome and Safari the following code exhibits the behavior

Client (TypeScript):

```
this.evSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8002/api/v1/notify');
this.evSource.addEventListener(
  'event',
  (x => console.log('we have ', x))
);
this.evSource.onmessage = (data => console.log(data));
this.evSource.onopen = (data => console.log(data));
this.evSource.onerror = (data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.evSource.close();
});
```

Server (Java):

```
// cache callback
public void eventCallback(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends Integer>> events) {
    for (CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends Integer> x : events) {
        LOGGER.info("{} Sending the following value: " + x.getValue(), Thread.currentThread().getId());
        final OutboundEvent sseEvent = new OutboundEvent.Builder().name("event")
                .data(Integer.class, x.getValue()).build();
        this.broadcaster.broadcast(sseEvent);
    }
}

@GET
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@ApiOperation(value = "Setup SSE pipeline", notes = "Sets up the notification pipeline for clients to access")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED,
                message = "Missing, bad or untrusted cookie"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK,
                message = "Events streamed successfully")
})
@Timed
@ResponseMetered
public EventOutput registerNotificationEvents(
        @HeaderParam(SseFeature.LAST_EVENT_ID_HEADER) String lastEventId,
        @QueryParam(SseFeature.LAST_EVENT_ID_HEADER) String lastEventIdQuery) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(lastEventId) || !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(lastEventIdQuery)) {
        LOGGER.info("Found Last-Event-ID header: {}", !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(lastEventId) ? lastEventId : lastEventIdQuery );
    }
    LOGGER.info("{} Received request", Thread.currentThread().getId());
    this.continuation = true;
    final EventOutput output = new EventOutput();

    broadcaster.add(output);

    Random rand = new Random();
    IntStream rndStream = IntStream.generate(() -> rand.nextInt(90));
    List<Integer> lottery = rndStream.limit(15).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    IgniteCache<Integer, Integer> cache = this.ignite.cache(topic_name);

    executorService.execute(() -> {
        try {
            lottery.forEach(value -> {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                    LOGGER.info("{} Sending the following value to Ignite: " + value + " : " + count++, Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    if (!cache.isClosed()) {
                        cache.put(1, value);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            continuation = false;
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            if (!output.isClosed()) {
                // THIS is where the client sees ALL the data broadcast
                // in one shot
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    LOGGER.info("{} Completing request", Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like http://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1673 captures the problem. GZip default won't flush even if upper levels ask for it. Solution is something like

`((AbstractServerFactory)configuration.getServerFactory()).getGzipFilterFactory().setSyncFlush(true);`

will enable flushing to synchronize with GZip if disabling GZip all up is not an option

Answer (score 0):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/966#issuecomment-271311044), webpack dev server compression buffers SSE instead of proxying instantaneously. This plagued me too!